# Sort directories by name's suffix

Tags: sorting, ls

I have the following list of directories:

> arquitectura-2col-layouttpl
>   bb-wap-portlet
>   bb-web-theme
>   bbwf2-portlet
>   canales-theme
>   columns_121_aeropuertos-layouttpl

Now I need to sort them by the name's suffix (portlet, theme or layouttpl) how can I accomplish that? The expected result would be:

> arquitectura-2col-layouttpl
>   columns_121_aeropuertos-layouttpl
>   bb-wap-portlet
>   bbwf2-portlet
>   canales-theme
>   bb-web-theme

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directories have variable number of `-` else you can use `-t` option in sort to specify delimiter...

Here's a workaround, provided directory names do not contain spaces in them. Assumes directory names are stored in a file called `ip.txt`, or pipe the output of `ls` directly. Also, see [perils of parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

```
$ sed 's/.*-/& /' ip.txt | sort -k2,2 | sed 's/ //'
arquitectura-2col-layouttpl
columns_121_aeropuertos-layouttpl
bb-wap-portlet
bbwf2-portlet
bb-web-theme
canales-theme
```